# How would I delete a row of data if none of the cells are empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with sales data for a given month for a number of different stores. There are approximately 450 rows (stores) to go through. The days of the month are in row 1, starting in column B, with the store numbers in column A, starting in row 2. What I need to find are the rows that are missing data for different days. I can use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that are empty, but that is still a lot to look at. What I am trying to do is reduce the amount of cells to look at by deleting any rows that are not missing data. So if a row is not missing any days of data, then I don't need to look at it, and can delete it. But if it is missing data, then keep the row. 
I'm stuck on figuring out the actual code, but I have come up with pseudo code for what I want:

```
foreach row in range ($B$2:$AB$450)
    foreach cell in row 
        if cell < 1
            delete row
    end foreach
end foreach
```

Here is an example of the spreadsheet:

```
        A           B               C               D
1               12/1/2019       12/2/2019       12/3/2019
2   Site 1          1000                            2000
3   Site 2          5000            5000            3000
4   Site 3          6000            4000            3000
```

In this example, rows 4 and 4 would be deleted because they are not missing any data.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far to the question?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a piece of that spreadsheet too. I'd say that it can probably be done with conditional formatting or filters

Comment: You could either use an AutoFilter, or Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0):

**assuming that you have 4 columns and they start in column B:

with an array formula you can see the length of characters in each row.

```
=MIN(LEN(B2:E2))
```

for example, you can use the above formula in row 2 (remember: ctrl+shift+enter to use it)

So, if you apply that formula per row, you should be able to know if you have missing value per row (all of them that have length 0 per row); then, use that column to filter. E.g. Filter anything that is not 0.